# How trigger mapDispatchToProps action in button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have problem with mapDispatchToProps. How can I "trigger" action from mapDispatchToProps using onClick in button?? - LoginForm.js. I know, I have a lot of to learn :D

```
class LoginForm extends Component{
render()
{
const {changeStatusLogin} = this;
return(
    <StyledContainer>
     <StyledTitle>Logowanie</StyledTitle>
                   <StyledForm className="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" id="login-nav">
                      <div className="form-group">
                         <label className="sr-only" htmlFor="exampleInputUsername2">Login</label>
                         <input className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" style={{textAlign: "center"}} placeholder="Login" required/>
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                         <label className="sr-only" htmlFor="exampleInputPassword2">Haslo</label>
                         <input type="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" style={{textAlign: "center"}} placeholder="Password" required/>
                      </div>
                         <Button type="submit"  className="btn btn-success" onClick={changeStatusLogin}>Zaloguj</Button>                                          
                   </StyledForm>
    </StyledContainer>
  )
 }
}
  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {return { 
  showLogin: state.showLogin}}

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {return {
  onChangeStatus: () => dispatch(loginAction.setTrue())}}

  export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps(LoginForm);
```

Comment: `const { changeStatusLogin } = this.props;`. Another thing - `changeStatusLogin` function is not declared anywhere, you should include it in your `mapDispatchToProps` function.

Comment: Make sure to accept an answer!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `connect`, the "connected" component will receive the dispatch functions as props.

You can access the props using the same names you gave them in `mapDispatchToProps`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onChangeStatus: () => dispatch(loginAction.setTrue())
  }
}
```

In your component, use it like this:

```
onChange(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  //no need to pass anything to this function
  this.props.onChangeStatus()
}

render(){
  return <button onClick={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but now when I click the button, I have this error: `TypeError: this.props.onChangeStatus is not a function...`

Comment: @DawidWójcik I just realized that you are not passing anything to your dispatch function. change the code to: `this.props.onChangeStatus()` inside of the `onChange()` function.

Comment: then it seems like the props are not being passed down properly. Are you importing `connect` and your action-creators into your file?

Comment: Yes, here is my code, maybe you find something. https://gist.github.com/D3AR316/d8ae40390f1c28341b12c49b041f3728

Comment: Here by using Routes:                                                                              
https://gist.github.com/D3AR316/ed4a59bfda6b4eee814a6f935e58f277

Comment: try separating your `LoginForm` component from your new component that is created with `connect` and then call that `"connected"` component in your route

Comment: So I need new component which will be "container" for `LoginForm` and using routes. Just then this component will be call in `StartPage`?

Comment: Yes. The container component will pass down the redux dispatchers to `LoginForm` and you will call the container component in your route

Comment: I fixed it. I had postponed bracket after return in mapDispatchToProps.